# Space seperators for numbers Google Script

Tags: string, google-apps-script, numbers

I have a string that contain results of the the SUM that have dynamic length that look like:

```
12345678
```

I have to display it with space separators:

```
12 345 678 //in looger
```

How can I do this with Google Script?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just formatted it with .00 at the end to use RegEx ('.' is a reference point). Then just sliced last three characters. Not elegant, but it works.

```
sum.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$& ').slice(0,-3)
```